# how to stop invisible videos of uicollectionviewcell in ios using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, avplayer

I want to stop playing of invisible videos of collectionview

I wrote for displaying cell in collectionview as follows

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
    var downloadingFileURL: AnyObject = arr_videos.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSUrl
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: downloadingFileURL)

    player1 = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    player1.play()
    var playerLayer1 = AVPlayerLayer(player: player1)
    playerLayer1.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    playerLayer1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, collectionview_videoslist.frame.size.width,collectionview_videoslist.frame.size.height);
    player1.volume = 1.0
    player1.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.Pause
    cell.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer1)
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Consider using the `prepareForReuse` method on UICollectionViewCell for that purpose. Although I'm not sure if it grants you a sufficient level of "precision".

Comment: @ArthurGevorkyan Thanks for your reply. How can I use it? Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: I assume, you have a custom cell class. Just override the aforementioned method and pause the embedded player in cell-wise way.